# Add space in comma separated alphanumeric regex

Tags: regex

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to apply a regex on an JSF input field, where 5 digits alphanumeric and spaces are allowed and if user wants to add multiple values they must be comma (,) separated.

So for single value:

```
k39Ka
```

For multiple value:

```
Kha93,0Lk3i,L9k K,lk hk
```

so far I am able to achieve this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]{5})*$
```

How can I allow spaces in the mentioned regex?

Comment: You could simply add `\s` within both of your square brackets, but this would mean that 5 white spaces would also be allowed. Is this something you would like as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a space to your brackets. I would use the following:

`(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{5}(,[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{5})*$)`

But you should check it here https://regex101.com/r/aK3zY9/1 to make sure it's what you want.